# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, rails-models

I have the following models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_products, foreign_key: 'order_foreign_id'
  has_many :order_variation_values, through: :order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_variation_values
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_variation_value
end

class OrderVariationValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_product, foreign_key: 'order_product_foreign_id'
end
```

When I try add record with nested_attributes I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection (Cannot modify association 'Order#order_variation_values' because the source reflection class 'OrderVariationValue' is associated to 'OrderProduct' via :has_many.):
  app/controllers/api/v2/orders_controller.rb:8:in 'create'`

What is wrong with the relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ***association set-up*** is wrong. It should be

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_products, foreign_key: 'order_foreign_id'
  has_many :order_variation_values, through: :order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_variation_values
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :order_variation_value
end

class OrderVariationValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_products, foreign_key: 'order_foreign_id'
  has_many :orders, through: :order_products
end
```

See these [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more Info.